# historical weather data APIs

Tags: web-applications, api

I am building a web application where I need to display whole year's month wise weather conditions. So that users get an idea of what the weather conditions are like and plan their trips accordingly.

I am using [WunderGround's History feature](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/history) but it does not give this data for smaller towns and destinations, even some very popular tourist destinations.

Are there any alternatives which could provide me the same information.

Answer (score 4):

From this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368722/are-there-any-weather-history-apis) on StackOverflow:

- [National Climatic Data Center (NCDC)](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/oa/ncdc.html) ([web services](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/ncdcwebservices))
- [World Weather Online](http://www.worldweatheronline.com/premium-weather.aspx?menu=historical) (paid)

More from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068043/weather-for-specific-date):

- [National Digital Forecast Database (NDFD) SOAP Web Service](http://www.nws.noaa.gov/xml/)
- [Wolfram Alpha for developers](http://products.wolframalpha.com/developers/)

And [even more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200984/where-can-i-find-historical-raw-weather-data):

- [Infochimps Geo API](http://www.infochimps.com/apis/geo)

Answer (score 1):

You can check [ClimaCell](https://www.climacell.co/weather-api/) for this. They have pretty detailed forecasts for anyone working on Big Data or need historical forecasts. Their history API goes as back as 20 years.

[image]

It's free for developers for a limit of 1000 calls per day which is more than enough for small-scale applications.

If you go through their [documentation](https://developer.climacell.co/v3/reference) they have legacy API in which you can define and list multiple locations. With your small town issue, you can define the town name by longitude and latitude and then reuse it.

[image]

You can set up webhooks and alerts also if you want to get notified for any updates.

[image]

**Javascript current forecast call**

```
var data = null;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("GET", "https://api.climacell.co/v3/weather/nowcast?unit_system=si&timestep=5&start_time=now&fields=");

xhr.send(data);

//RESPONSE
    [{
        "lat": 42.30260171891152,
        "lon": -71.17609710203855,
        "precipitation": {
            "value": 0.39,
            "units": "in/hr"
        },
        "precipitation_type": {
            "value": "rain"
        },
        "observation_time": {
            "value": "2020-05-15T21:00:00.000Z"
        }
    }]
```

You can try their [sandbox](https://developer.climacell.co/v3/reference#get-locations) panel for more API calls.